# Publishing by Air Android Flash 5.5 , showing me an error

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm creating an android app using AS3 Flash CS5.5
it'a about simple library contains images that are uploaded to a web page , and i'm using this code that someone help me `

```
//THIS DEFINES THE ARRAY WHERE YOUR LOADERS WILL GO
var pictureArray:Array = new Array;

//THIS CODE TARGETS THE BUTTONS -- WHEN YOU CLICK THEM THE FUNCTIONS 'nextpic' and 'lastpic' WILL FIRE
nextbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextpic)
backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, lastpic)


//YOUR LOADERS. I'VE PUT 3 PICTURES IN THE LIBRARY
//THE LAST LINE FOR EACH LOADER 'PUSHES' THE LOADER INTO THE ARRAY

var loader1 = new Loader();
loader1.load(new URLRequest("banana.jpg"));
pictureArray.push(loader1);

var loader2 = new Loader();
loader2.load(new URLRequest("big apple.jpg"));
pictureArray.push(loader2);

var loader3 = new Loader();
loader3.load(new URLRequest("pineapple.jpg"));
pictureArray.push(loader3);


//WE ADD THE FIRST 'CHILD' HERE
//NOTE THAT ARRAYS HOLD OBJECTS IN CONSECTUTIVE POSITIONS: 0 - WHATEVER
//THE FIRST OBJECT IN THE ARRAY IS ADDRESSED AT: ARRAYNAME[0], THE SECOND OBJECT IS 
//AT ARRAYNAME[1], ETC.

addChild(pictureArray[0]);
pictureArray[0].x = 110; pictureArray[0].y = 80; 


//n IS JUST A COUNTER THAT WILL MAKE IT EASIER TO ADDRESS THE ITEMS IN THE ARRAY
var n:int = 0;                                  


Function nextpic(e)
{
  removeChild(pictureArray[n]);
  n = n+1; 

  //HERE WE RESET THE POSITION IN THE ARRAY IF WE'VE GONE PAST THE NUMBER OF PICTURES THAT WE HAVE
  if (n>pictureArray.length - 1)
    n=0;

  addChild(pictureArray[n]);
  pictureArray[n].x = 110; pictureArray[n].y = 80; 
}

function lastpic(e)
{
  removeChild(pictureArray[n]);
  n = n-1;
  if (n<0)
    n=pictureArray.length - 1;

  addChild(pictureArray[n]);
  pictureArray[n].x = 110; pictureArray[n].y = 80; 
}`
```

it's working well , but when I publish it by Android Air , it shows me this error

`Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 39 1071: Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute Function, not nextpic.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re-write `Function` as `function`   Easy!